# Calculate Factors to Achieve Goal

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm having a challenge in resolving an algebraic problem using excel and would really appreciate some help.

Scenario:

- Call center has goal of answering 80% of calls offered within X time
- Sum of calls currently answered at goal is 369
- Forecast remaining calls in day is 1854

Objective:

- How many calls need to be answered during the remaining intervals in order to reach the day goal?

[call table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xi9A.png)

If the total avg by 9:30 AM -->
=SUM(C2:C25)/SUM(B2:B25)
equals 0.647 how many of the remaining forecast calls each interval need to be answered at goal in order for the total avg goal of 0.80 by end of day?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an easy math way to do this but I'm sick so I used the solver.

We set the solver to make the target cell in green equal to the given value of 0.8 by adjusting the value in the yellow cell.

By adjusting the yellow cell, the sum total of accepted calls in the day changes, which adjusts the weighted average acceptance rate in the day as shown in the green cell.

[image]

So the average for the remainder of the day must by 84.7% or higher so that the daily rate meets the goal of 80%

Answer (score 0):

Without Excel

1. calls offered + call forecast = total expected calls
2. total expected calls X 80% = calls to meet goal
3. calls to meet goal - calls answered = forecasted calls needed to be answered to meet goals

I leave it up to you to translate this (one cell or several is up to you) to excel